# Company installation error

Tags: spacemacs, golang, company

trying to setup go auto completion (using spacemacs), facing an issue while installing company

```
In end of data:
company-tng.el:198:1:Warning: the function ‘eglot--snippet-expansion-fn’ is
not known to be defined.

In end of data:
company-yasnippet.el:177:1:Warning: the function ‘yas-minor-mode’ is not known
to be defined.
```

Please suggest a solution
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got solution from [Gitter](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs?at=5f42bae2765d633c54aa846b) Just ignore those errors. Add completion layer, use develop branch